# LSTM Sequential Model, Predict future Values on M15 chart for one day

Tags: jupyter-notebook, lstm, prediction, sequential, forex

Hello Stackoverflow members,

I have built up an LSTM Seuqential Model for Forex M15 Values, specifically for the pair EURUSD, with typical_price as the price type.

Now after setting up and train the model, I would like to predict, extrapolate the typical_price for one future day.

In my dataset I took the data for one month (January 2017) from 1st to 30th as training and testing dataset (1920 values). Now I would like to extrapolate the prices for the 31th of January. I cannot really resolve what the model likes as input data and shape, to extrapolate the data from the last value of the 30th of January.

Can someone give me a hint or explain what the function **`model.predict()`** needs as input values?

---

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

from subprocess import check_output
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.cross_validation import  train_test_split
import time #helper libraries
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import newaxis
from keras.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

import  time

df = pd.read_csv('EURUSD15.csv')
df.columns = ['date','time','open','high','low','close','vol']
df['date']=df['date'].str.replace('.','-')
J = df[(df['date'] > '2017-01-01') & (df['date'] < '2017-01-30')]
J['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(J['date'].apply(str)+' '+J['time'])
J['tp']=((J['high']+J['low']+J['close'])/3)
EURUSD = J[['timestamp','open','high','low','close','vol','tp']]
df = EURUSD.drop(['timestamp','open','high','low','close','vol'], axis=1)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
df = scaler.fit_transform(df)

def window_transform_series(series,window_size):
    # containers for input/output pairs
    dataX = []
    datay = []

    for i in range(window_size, len(series)):
    dataX.append(series[i - window_size:i])
    datay.append(series[i])

    # reshape
    dataX = np.asarray(dataX)
    dataX.shape = (np.shape(dataX)[0:2])
    datay = np.asarray(datay)
    datay.shape = (len(datay),1)

    return dataX,datay

window_size = 50
dataX,datay = window_transform_series(series = df, window_size = window_size)

train_test_split = int(np.ceil(2*len(datay)/float(3))) # set the split point


# partition the training set
# X_train = dataX[:train_test_split,:]
# y_train = datay[:train_test_split]

# partition the training set
X_train = dataX[:train_test_split,:]
y_train = datay[:train_test_split]

#keep the last chunk for testing
X_test = dataX[train_test_split:,:]
y_test = datay[train_test_split:]

# NOTE: to use keras's RNN LSTM module our input must be reshaped
X_train = np.asarray(np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], window_size, 1)))
X_test = np.asarray(np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], window_size, 1)))

import keras
np.random.seed(0)

#Build an RNN to perform regression on our time series input/output data
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(window_size, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08,     decay=0.0)

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=64, verbose=1)

train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)


# print out training and testing errors
training_error = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
print('training error = ' + str(training_error))

testing_error = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('testing error = ' + str(testing_error))

training error = 0.0001732897365647525
testing error = 0.00019586048660112955

%matplotlib inline

#plot original series
plt.plot(df, color = 'k')

# plot training set prediction
split_pt = train_test_split + window_size
plt.plot(np.arange(window_size,split_pt,1),train_predict,color = 'b')

# plot testing set prediction
plt.plot(np.arange(split_pt,split_pt + len(test_predict),1), test_predict,color ='r')

# pretty up graph
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.ylabel('(normalized) price of EURUSD')
plt.legend(['original series','training fit','testing fit'],loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to be open, highest, lowest price, volume. So you can predict closing price for some imaginary date or you can model.predict(X_test[30]). But one line in your code is strange - the line where you drop all yours features. I wonder how yout X_train[0] looks like.

Comment: Yes i know. I calculatetd the typical price, since i wanted this price type to be calculated. I could have just as well taken any other price type. But it makes no difference for the model i guess, since the procedure always includes, dropping all the other features and then rescaling the one feature left.

Comment: You predict average price (J['tp']=((J['high']+J['low']+J['close'])/3)) - it is your y_test, based on the same variable but for a few past days.  Answer to your question: input to model.predict function could be X_test[0]. It is average price (tp) for a 'windows_size' days.